# Try/Catch/Finnaly with ESLint Expected to return a value at the end of async arrow function

Tags: javascript, try-catch, eslint, arrow-functions

I have this ESLint error in my code:

function(productId: any): Promise
Expected to return a value at the end of async arrow function

```
export const getGooglePlayPayment = async (productId) => {
  await InAppBilling.close();
  try {
    await InAppBilling.open();

    if (!await InAppBilling.isSubscribed(productId)) {
      const details = await InAppBilling.subscribe(productId);
      console.log('You purchased: ', details);
      return details.purchaseState === PAYMENT_STATE.PurchasedSuccessfully;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return false;
  } finally {
    await InAppBilling.consumePurchase(productId);
    await InAppBilling.close();
  }
};
```

Someone can help me to fix this issue without having to disabled the ESLing rule :)

thanks

Comment: In your try block you have return type inside **if** but what about outside? try block should return something if your code execution does not go into **if** block

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rule here is [consistent-return](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/consistent-return).

You are not returning anything if the `if` statement in the `try` block is not fulfilled. You should return something if the `isSubscribed` call is truthy:

```
export const getGooglePlayPayment = async (productId) => {
  await InAppBilling.close();
  try {
    await InAppBilling.open();

    if (!await InAppBilling.isSubscribed(productId)) {
      const details = await InAppBilling.subscribe(productId);
      console.log('You purchased: ', details);
      return details.purchaseState === PAYMENT_STATE.PurchasedSuccessfully;
    }
    return 'Already subscribed';
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return false;
  } finally {
    await InAppBilling.consumePurchase(productId);
    await InAppBilling.close();
  }
};
```

(Of course, replace `Already subscribed` with whatever would make most sense there. If you just want to indicate that the transaction succeeded, perhaps `return true`. The important thing is to distinguish it from the `return false` in the `catch`.)